# multivariate Student's t distribution: intuition for non-independence?

Tags: independence, intuition, t-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Consider a multivariate Student's t distribution, with parameters $\nu$ (d.f.), $\mu$ (location) and $\Sigma$ (shape).

Does anyone have a good intuition for the individual components not being statistically independent, even when $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: consider writing the t as $Z/\sqrt{V/\nu}$ where $Z$ is multivariate normal and $V$ is univariate chi-squared and independent of $Z$. If $\Sigma$ is diagonal, components of $Z$ are independent, but then you are dividing each component by a common factor. The resulting elliptical distribution - even when its axes are aligned with the variable axes - does not have independent components.

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b.  Let me try to check one last step in my intuition: if, rather than dividing your $Z$ by $\sqrt{\frac{V}{\nu}}$, I divided it by $2$, I would still have a rv whose components were statistically independent.  Thus, the common factor needs to be stochastic: were it not, then knowing $X_1$ doesn't provide any further information about $X_2$ because I already knew the common factor; with a stochastic factor, knowing $X_1$ does provide further information about $X_2$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "intuition" means?  Independence implies the conditional distributions are all the same.  However, inspection of the formula for the PDF (in two dimensions $x,y$) readily shows the conditional distributions of $y$ at given values of $x$ have identical shapes but are scaled by $(1+x^2/\nu)^{1/2},$ which is nonzero when $x\ne 0.$  Would that be "intuitive" or not?

Comment: Thanks @whuber.  Your question is deeper than mine.  I'll answer by example, maybe just replacing the word 'intuition' with 'simple': I wanted a simple explanation of what goes 'wrong' with the diagonal matrix intuition that works for the Gaussian - why does squashing the peak and fattening the tails break the intuition that the major axes' alignment with the coordinate axes leads to independence?

Comment: @Colin you need the denominator to vary, yes. That common value within the vector but varying across draws of the random variable creates dependence between components. Consider a bivariate case and take vertical slices through the bivariate density (conditional densities) -- they don't all have the same shape. Edit: Ah, ... whuber covers that in his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's *look* at the situation.  As a point of departure we will first study the bivariate standard Normal distribution.  I will do this by plotting vertical slices through its graph: these are given by the functions

$$y\to \phi(x,y)$$

for $x = 0, \pm 1/2,  \pm 1, \pm 3/2, \pm 2$ (where $\phi$ is the bivariate density).  The reason for doing this is that variables $(X,Y)$ are independent if and only if the conditional distribution $Y\mid X=x$ does not vary with $x.$

[image: Figure 1]

As $x$ increases, the density grows smaller and the slices shrink down to the axis in the plots at the left.  However, if we *normalize* these curves (rescaling each one vertically) so that each has unit area, thereby turning them into the *conditional* densities, they all coincide, as shown at the right.  This is how we can tell $Y$ is independent of $X.$

Here is the same situation for a multivariate t distribution with $\nu=1$ degree of freedom (in two variables).

[image: Figure 2]

The conditional densities, although centered at $0,$ have different shapes: *they vary with $x.$*  You can see that they spread out as $|x|$ grows larger.  This can (easily) be demonstrated algebraically by examining the formula for the multivariate t density.

Here is a "hand-waving" demonstration that might help us calibrate our intuition.

As Glen_b pointed out in comments, the Multivariate t is the distribution of standard multivariate Normal vector $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_d)$ divided by an independent positive variable $Z.$  (A multiple of $Z^2$ has a Gamma distribution, but that detail doesn't matter.)

Consider what happens to the preceding conditional distributions as $|X_1/Z|$ increases.  When $|X_1/Z|$ is relatively large, it likely got that way through a combination of a large value of $|X_1|$ and a *smaller* than average value of $Z.$  Because $Z$ was small, and $Z$ simultaneously divides all the components of $X$, the values of $X_2/Z, X_3/Z, \ldots, X_d/Z$ (which obviously are scaled by the relatively *large* quantity $1/Z$) will thereby be more spread out.  The larger $|X_1|$ gets, the larger $Z$ is likely to be and the more the other components are spread.

Because the conditional distributions of the $X_i/Z$ become more spread out as $|X_1/Z|$ increases, the $X_i/Z$ cannot be independent of $X_1/Z.$